# Evaluation of product limit

Tags: limits

> $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1- \dfrac1 {n^2}\right)= ?$

Attempt:

Simplified it to $\dfrac{(n-1)(n+1)}{n^2}$ , and then wrote some terms to observe the cancelllation pattern, but that didn't help, how to solve it then?

Comment: Hint: Use your simplified form to show  
$$\prod_{n=2}^{m} \left(1- \dfrac1 {n^2}\right)= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(m+2)}{\Gamma(m+1)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Are you allowed to use Euler's infinite product formula for sine? $$\sin x = x \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2 \pi^2}\right)$$